# Ivy Revision Scheme Out of Sync

Tags: ant, ivy

I have a project that publishes its jars to ivy. For code that is currently in development it publishes as 1.DEV.x. This has worked mostly well for keeping everyone integrating on track.

I have noticed the minor versions have no longer matched and I would like to match them back up. For example, some dependencies show a minor version of 60, while some show 10. In fact, they have completely stopped incrementing revisions at all. This is bad because now for projects to properly resolve, they must run a `clean-ivy-cache` command to pick up the changes.

Today, I cleared all 1.DEV.x dependencies from ivy by deleting all containing folders. There are a few dependencies that have started at minor version 6 (not sure why its not 0) and the rest at their usual number. The current problem is now the projects that depend on these can't seem to find them. For example, one dependency with minor version 6 says it found it at version 7, but when trying to download, throws an error because it isn't there. The work around is to create the folder, rename the dependencies, and re run the build.

I would like to have it start over at minor version 0, and would also like it to continue incrementing. I can't seem to find anywhere where that could be reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the dependencies and the configuration. When you publish, look at the two sets of files being uploaded.. clear both of these.